# Python KeyError from CSV data file

Tags: python, csv

I receive this error:

```
line 121, in <module>
    data=convertData(data,header)
line 86, in convertData 
    Data.append([row[item] for item in header])
KeyError: 'ELEM'
```

The code is:

```
def convertData(data,header):
    Data=[]
    for row in data:
        Data.append([row[item] for item in header])   !line 86
    return Data

data=convertData(data,header)       !line 121
writeTable(data,header,'%s %s Data' % (line,lc),'table%s%s.tex' % (line,lc))
```

The data and header are from a *.csv file.  A sample of the .csv data is:

```
ELEM  EType     OD      T       Tc      
1     16        2.375   0.462   0.462
```

I am not sure what the problem is.  Can anyone help me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you are reading the .csv file with `csv.reader` which returns numerically-indexed rows of data.

Instead of looking for ie `row["ELEM"]` try `row[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your error, but in case you would like to use `numpy` to avoid these csv troubles:

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.genfromtxt('dat.txt', dtype=float, delimiter='\t', skip_header=1)
print dat    # all data in 2d array
```

Or if you like to keep the column names:

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.genfromtxt('dat.txt', dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names=True)
print dat['ELEM']    # the first column accessed by its names
```

**Assumption**: your data column separated by `tab`.